# Java dependency

Tags: google-chrome, java

I was hoping someone could help out with this.

Last night I got an update notification on my computer advising that there was a newer version of Java available, when I selected to update it, I was given the option to remove since it appeared to have been unused for 6 months.

After selecting to remove it, I then noticed this morning that my web browsers were running very slow, both Chrome and the new Edge which is built on Chrome/Chromium.

I then opted to reinstall Java and now my web browsers are running fine, as they were prior to uninstalling.

I checked online and have found that Chrome should have no Java dependent apps.

So was wondering, is this a coincidence? Or does Java have an effect on web browsing?

Comment: You might have some extension, perhaps from an Office suite or antivirus application or somewhere else, that is dependent on Java and is causing the problems. I have not had Java installed on machines for years and the browsers work perfectly.

Comment: I have machines here and at clients set up with / without Java and browsing is the same on all. I agree with the above to check extensions. I remove Chrome Extensions that I do not use and the few that I have do not require Java.